# `cannot load plugin` when debugging golang file in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, plugins

My program first needs a plugin when running in Ubuntu:

```
go build -race -buildmode=plugin ../mrapps/wc.go
```

When I made `launch.json` and tried to debug a file in VSCode:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch mrworker",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "src/main/mrworker.go",
            "args": ["wc.so"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The console showed `cannot load plugin wc.so`:

```
Starting: /home/lzq/go/bin/dlv-dap dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:44503 --log-dest=3 from /home/lzq/Document/MapReduce/6.824/src/main
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:44503
Type 'dlv help' for list of commands.
2022/01/09 22:38:32 cannot load plugin wc.so
Process 17678 has exited with status 1
Detaching
dlv dap (17594) exited with code: 0
```

When I used `dlv` to find more information, the error is `plugin was built with a different version of package`.

I read many posts but none of them works. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin) :

Currently plugins are only supported on Linux, FreeBSD, and macOS as mentioned in latest version of Golang.
Dependencies between exe binary and plugin object do not match exactly that's why plugin loader is throwing the above error.

Go uses minimal version selection. It’s quite hard to pin transitive dependencies because Go will select the minimal version that it thinks satisfies the dependency tree in just your plugin code project without any way to make it clear that there’s another dependency tree to consider.

There are plenty of workaround to deal with this issue :

Refer this link : https://forum.heroiclabs.com/t/plugin-was-built-with-a-different-version-of-package/556/5 , https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31354

OR

You can try to build plugin with `-gcflags "all=-N -l"` flag.

For better understanding refer this : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-6288

Also you can try with `replace` in `go.mod` file
example :

```
replace github.com/zimnx/central => ../central
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference from the dlv github [issues](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2873)

And the corresponding solution:

> Delve passes -gcflags="all=-N -l" to go build, because of how plugin
> works the plugin needs to also be built like that.